# What is the link to the reference page of free-form input command?

Tags: documentation

I see that WolframAlpha input has its command `WolframAlpha[]`.

I cannot find similar command for free-form input. `FreeForm[]` is not a valid command. What is the link to the reference page of free-form input command?

Comment: [`Workflow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterFreeFormInput.html) and [`Guide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) with the second argument `"WolframParse"`, `"WolframResult"` or `"Result"`.

```
WolframAlpha["Europe", "WolframResult"]
(* Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"] *)

WolframAlpha["highest mountain in Europe", "WolframResult"]
(* {Entity["Mountain", "MountElbrus"]} *)

WolframAlpha["highest mountain in Europe", "WolframParse"]
(* HoldComplete[
    EntityClass[
     "Mountain", {EntityProperty["Mountain", "Continent"] -> 
       Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"], 
      EntityProperty["Mountain", "Elevation"] -> TakeLargest[1]}]] *)

WolframAlpha["highest mountain in Europe", "Result"]
(* EntityClass["Mountain", {EntityProperty["Mountain", "Continent"] -> 
    Entity["GeographicRegion", "Europe"], 
     EntityProperty["Mountain", "Elevation"] -> TakeLargest[1]}] *)
```